# Error: Couldn't find a style target. It started to appear after SSR with React implementation. How to fix?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd, server-side-rendering, webpack-style-loader

I had a CSR app and now implemented Server-Side Rendering (SSR) with React, and get this error
Error: Couldn't find a style target

We used reactDOMserver, react-app-wire, with webpack-override file
**See webpack configs below:**

```
const { resolve } = require("path");
require("ignore-styles");

module.exports = {
  webpack: function (config) {
    config.entry = resolve(dirname, "../client/src/ssr");
    config.optimization = undefined;
    config.output = {
      filename: "ssr.js",
      globalObject: 'this',
      libraryTarget: "commonjs",
      path: resolve(dirname, "../client/build"),
    };
    return config;
  },
};
```

**from server**

```
app.get("^/$", (req, res) => {
  Object.assign(global, {
    navigation: {},
    window: ssr.getWindow(),
    navigator: {
      userAgent: req.headers["user-agent"],
    },
    global: {},
    document:ssr.ssrDocument
  });
  const App = require("./build/ssr");
  const context = {};

  let app = App.default(req.url, context);
```

**then res,render app**

**AND SSR JS FILE**

```
ssr.js file  :
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
for renderToString(
....
<App/>
....
)
```

And received Error: Couldn't find a style target
I had a CSR app and now implemented Server-Side Rendering (SSR) with React, and get this error
Error: Couldn't find a style target. This probably means that the value for the 'insert' parameter is invalid
Get this error when I run the server and try to access the page.

---

**We also tried other approaches with these loaders:**
css-loader, sass loader and style-loader and even with   isomorphic-style-loader
They led to the error with No PostCSS config and after fixing this by adding to the project postcss.config.js file AND AFTER we received same error about style target and additional error with antd
Error: No PostCSS Config found in: D:_PROJECT....\client\node_modules\antd\dist

---

Tech sack in use: nodejs, reactjs, antdesign, babel and webpack.
I already tried a lot of solutions from StackOverflow and other sources, nothing helped!

Please, help me to solve it.

Thank you!

Comment: how you are approaching ssr? with reactDOMServer ?

Comment: @Solvenc1no only renderToString() with react-app-rewired and webpack-override file

Comment: @Solvenc1no import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use style-loader server side.
Find the loader like this: https://github.com/codebandits/react-app-rewire-css-modules/blob/master/index.js just use style-loader instead, and remove it.. or switch to `razzle`